# Deserializing datetime double encodes date

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to deserialize a datetime value:

```
def default(o):
    if type(o) is datetime.date or type(o) is datetime.datetime:
        return o.isoformat()


def get_user_join_date(user):

    return json.dumps(  
        user.date_joined,
        sort_keys=True,
        indent=1,
        default=default
    )
```

in order to use it as a value in payload:

```
def jwt_payload_handler(user, active_site):
    payload = {
        "id": user.id,
        "date": get_user_join_date(user),
        "username": user.username, 
        "role": user.role
    }
```

The problem is that my datetime ends up being double encoded (it has 2 double quotes)

> date: ""2018-09-27T12:32:17.577000+00:00""

Any idea why this might be happening and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that the date string is encoded twice.

The return value of `get_user_join_date(user)` is the string `'"2018-09-27T12:32:17.577000+00:00"'` (so the ISO formatted datetime surrounded by double quotes).

This string is put into the payload and is again dumped to JSON by whatever you're using to create the JWT token.

A reduced example of what you are seeing would be this:

```
import json
import datetime

def default(o):
    if type(o) is datetime.date or type(o) is datetime.datetime:
        return o.isoformat()

print(json.dumps({
    'date': json.dumps(
        datetime.datetime.now(),
        default=default
    )
}))
```

Which produces the output you are seeing:

```
{"date": "\"2018-10-09T12:53:04.914694\""}
```

There are a few solutions to this issue:

1. The easiest solution to this issue would be to not use `json.dumps` in `get_user_join_date` and simply return `user.date_joined.isoformat()` instead.
2. Another solution would be to return `user.date_joined` from `get_user_join_date` and somehow pass the custom `default` function to the JSON encoder used by whatever is processing that JWT payload.
3. It might also be possible to just return the date object from `get_user_join_date`, but only if the library you're using is smart enough to handle datetime objects (some are).